# Grails Plugin overrides controller and views

Tags: grails, plugins, module

I have a modular application where in one module I have spring security ui(s2-ui) setup, with some controllers and views overridden. 
In the other module I'm having troubles because grails is not using the spring security ui(s2-ui) configured in the first module but rather a fresh s2-ui installed as a result of the dependency of the first module on s2-ui.

For example, I've customized the register controller and views but this is not being reflected in the 2nd module.

FYI I've set the loadsAfter property to tell my plugin to load after the s2-ui plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the overridden views and controllers are local to the first plugin, then you need to copy them to the second plugin as well.  The second plugin is inheriting the base plugin files from your home folder.

Comment: I know that copying the custom views from the first plugin resolves the problem in the application but that isn't DRY. I was looking for a more elegant solution if there is any.